# ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

Tags: java, oracle

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
txtFechaNacimientoEmpleado.setText(tbproductos.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
```

y en el campo se muestra lo siguiente: 1976-01-01 00:00:00.0

E intento actualizar la tabla y es donde aparece el error que he mencionado.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No sé por qué pones la etiqueta mysql en tu pregunta cuando el error es de Oracle. [Aquí por ejemplo](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-when-using-the-date-function-with-oracle?lang=es-es) se explica cuál puede ser el motivo del error, y se encuentra en una consulta SQL que envías a tu BD Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

### Lo que sucedes es que estas utilizando un formato de fecha que no maneja la base de datos por eso obtienes el error de la base de datos;

ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

Revisa la configuración de su base de datos o que tipo de formato de fecha tiene configurada para esta columna saludos